# Nested unions supported in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, union

MySQL version: 5.1.36

```
(select 
    1 as num) 
union
(
    (select 
        2 as num) 
    union
    (select 
        3 as num))
```

Above query throws syntax error.

MySQL doesn't support nesting of unions? The MySQL doc. is silent on this.

Answer (score 4):

I admit that I've never tried to nest a `UNION`, probably because the following query is equivalent and is acceptable:

```
(SELECT
    1 AS num) 
UNION
(SELECT
    2 AS num) 
UNION
(SELECT
    3 AS num)
```

Comment: True, that in this case nesting a UNION has no impact, but in the case where aggregate functions like SUM are involved, nesting has its uses.

Comment: Yes, I tried nested count unions and it gives me 'MySQL doesn't yet support 'nesting of unions at the right-hand side'